# KeyError: "Unknown task summarization, available tasks are ['feature-extraction', 'sentiment-analysis', 'ner', 'question-answering', 'fill-mask']"

Tags: python, nlp, summarization

I am trying to do text summarization for a column in that data frame. I followed the steps mentioned in this site (https://towardsdatascience.com/summarization-of-covid-research-papers-using-bart-model-5b109a6669a6) but I am getting this error

**KeyError: "Unknown task summarization, available tasks are ['feature-extraction', 'sentiment-analysis', 'ner', 'question-answering', 'fill-mask']"**

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK85T.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should update your transformers library:

> `pip install -U transformers`

```
from transformers import pipeline

# use bart in pytorch
summarizer = pipeline("summarization")
summarizer("An apple a day, keeps the doctor away", min_length=5, max_length=20)

# use t5 in tf
summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="t5-base", tokenizer="t5-base", framework="tf")
summarizer("An apple a day, keeps the doctor away", min_length=5, max_length=20)
```